# Setting external webapp logging configuration with Jetty and log4j

Tags: web-applications, log4j, classpath, jetty

I have a webapp packaged as a war which I deploy in Jetty (version 6.1.25). The web app makes use of log4j. I would like to be able to configure the webapp logging via a config file which is external to the war (i.e. not burnt in).

I've tried using a custom context WebAppContext with an extra class path property pointing to the log4j.properties file that I want to inject to the webapp classpath, but this did not work.

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/quantel</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/quantel</Set>
  <Set name="extraClasspath">quantel/log4j.properties</Set>
</Configure>
```

I get the following error message:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Is it possible to do this with Jetty?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've adjusted the xml configuration above to add the folder containing the log4j config file to the webapp classpath, instead of just adding the config file itself. It is now working, but it is not clear to me why.

My working configuration looks like:

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/quantel</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/quantel</Set>
  <Set name="extraClasspath"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/quantel</Set>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Classpath entries must be either directories or jars.  log4j will look for the log4j.properties file INSIDE each entry on the classpath.  So if you put 'quantel/log4j.properties' on the classpath, it will try to treat it as a jar and look for log4j.properties inside it (which will fail).  Instead, if you put 'quantel' on the classpath, it will look for log4j.properties inside that directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set the logging level to debug, add a java option on jvm start-up arguments:

```
vi ${jetty.base}/start.d/start.ini:

--exec
-Dlog4j.debug
```

If you want a full control of logging configuration without access of WAR, also add a java option:

```
--exec
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:resources/log4j.xml
```

See also：

[External log4j property file with Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28326026/1244488)

[advanced-jetty-start](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.0.6.v20130930/advanced-jetty-start.html)