# External log4j property file with Jetty

Tags: log4j, jetty, slf4j

I'm migrating a bunch of our webapps (run in Jetty) from log4j to slf4j.  Previously, log4j would find the log4j.properties file from jetty.home/resources/log4j.properties.  After moving to slf4j, the external log4j.properties file is not found and everything is getting logged to stderror.

If I build the same log4j.properties file inside the war, everything works as expected (and as it did previously).  What am I doing wrong? I'd like to use an external logging config in jetty.home/resources as opposed to building it into the war.

In each webapp war, I have `log4j-1.2.17`, `slf4j-api-1.7.10` and the binder `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10`.

The Jetty start.ini is `OPTIONS=Server,jmx,resources,websocket`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding the `-Dlog4j.debug` java option to the start-up script.  In doing so, I found that log4j was picking up a log4j.properties file from within the war that had been added for test.

The two options I found for fixing this were either remove the embedded config file, or add a start-up option.  I was able to move module's log4j file to it's root so that it was excluded from the maven build.  This way, it is still available locally (for test) but not built into the war.

The other option that worked was to add `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:resources/log4j.properties`
to the start-up options.  This approach seems a bit convoluted but will override the embedded file.